# obtaining pre-signed request from heroku

Tags: python, heroku, amazon-s3

I'm looking at the heroku documentation (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3-upload-python) about making a direct upload to S3 using a pre-signed request from heroku.

For the code below, are you expected to send the actual file to Heroku to obtain the pre-signed request or can you just send the file info (name, type, etc.)?

```
@app.route('/sign_s3/')
def sign_s3():
  S3_BUCKET = os.environ.get('S3_BUCKET')

  file_name = request.args.get('file_name')
  file_type = request.args.get('file_type')

  s3 = boto3.client('s3')

  presigned_post = s3.generate_presigned_post(
    Bucket = S3_BUCKET,
    Key = file_name,
    Fields = {"acl": "public-read", "Content-Type": file_type},
    Conditions = [
      {"acl": "public-read"},
      {"Content-Type": file_type}
    ],
    ExpiresIn = 3600
  )

  return json.dumps({
    'data': presigned_post,
    'url': 'https://%s.s3.amazonaws.com/%s' % (S3_BUCKET, file_name)
  })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you posted uses only the file name and type to generate an S3 pre-signed URL, so it's not using the file.

Once the server generates this S3 URL, it will send it to the client so it can use this URL to upload the file.

So the answer is no, your file is not sent to Heroku, just the file info. The file will be directly sent from the client side to S3.

More information on S3 pre-signed URLs can be found [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html)